# Cannot seem to get the buttons to open a new MapActivity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've been playing around with this for some time now and am hoping that someone smarter than I will be able to help. My boss has given me an opportunity to learn to develop Android apps and I'm struggling with this one issue. I need to build several apps with multiple activities but can't seem to get past this point. I'm sure it's a problem in my coding, but with so many different ways of doing things, I'm a little confused at this point.

I am building an app that opens a Main activity with two buttons on the page. One is the close button and works fine. I want the next button to open a mapActivity that is set to my campus' location. I am not a student working on a project I just work for a community college. ;-)

What's really wierd is that the EXACT same google.maps code works fine by itself. I just can't get the button to open the Activity without crashing.

Here is my manifest.xml, main.xml, my main.java, Map.java and map.xml. would you please comment and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Dave

here are two errors:

```
11-21 14:50:58.968: W/dalvikvm(437): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-21 14:50:58.978: E/AndroidRuntime(437): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=edu.mtsac.mapproject.MAP }
```

This says the Activity was not found but I can see it in my source files, and in the manifest here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.mtsac.mapproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Main" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- map activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Map"
        android:name=".Map" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="edu.mtsac.mapproject.MAP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Main.xml and Map.xml files are simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mapBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Map" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0jevUfyLD_b1Eikgpm_mo7KVDspzhPJdRDDaxEw"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the Main.java

```
package edu.mtsac.mapproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Button mapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
             mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Map.class));
                 }
            });


        Button closeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
    closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

};// end onCreate()
}
```

and lastly the Map.java

```
package edu.mtsac.mapproject;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Map extends MapActivity {

MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
MapView mapview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapview.displayZoomControls(true);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapview.setSatellite(true);

    mc = mapview.getController();
    String coord[] = { "34.047517", "-117.847050" };

    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coord[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coord[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17);
    mapview.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any activity in your manifest registered to handle this action `edu.mtsac.mapproject.MAP`. I assume that exception is happening when you call:

```
startActivity(new Intent("edu.mtsac.mapproject.MAP"));
```

It looks like you're probably trying to start your Map Activity for which you don't need to specify an Action. Just do something like:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Map.class));
```

You probably want to read this [doc on intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) to understand what's really going on here and how you should be using these classes.

Answer (score 0):

In the "map" button click implementation you create an Intent whose action is `"edu.mtsac.mapproject.MAP"`. Since your manifest's Intent Filter is looking for action `"android.intent.action.MAP"` it will not resolve to your activity.

I believe you were confused by explicit vs. implicit intents. Explicit intents use the specific name of the activity you want to use but implicit intents only define an action you want to accomplish.

To get this to work change the map button to start the action in your manifest.

Comment: I changed it to this:

    Button mapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
         mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Map.class));
             }
         });

Is this what you mean?

Comment: In addition, I tried changing both the manifest and the Main so they match. First I used "edu.mtsac.mapproject" Then the other. Neither made any difference.

Comment: This is very strange, try the explicit Intent again with the fully qualified class name in the manifest.

Comment: Yes Strange it is! I will try your suggestion and get back here with my results once I'm done. 

Thanks Again! To Everyone who responded. Hopefully we'll get this figured out...

Comment: @kabuko, - not sure what the problem is with this code, but I am unable to make it work. Please, if someone would be so kind and paste it into their environment and see if they can get it to work, then it may prove that my environment is the issue rather than the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your Main.java, try to use this code instead:

```
    Button mapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
    mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Map.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't change anything. It still crashes.

Comment: Yes same error. I made a few changes to the code as suggested here by you and the others. but still no difference. Would you consider pasting my code into your environment so I can eliminate the set-up as the issue? I think the problem may be my environment.